# Should you 'gradle clean' before creating a jar using 'gradle jar'?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

Hi I have a study question that I cannot seem to figure out the answer to. I am very new to gradle and am not sure why it is wrong to build before creating a jar?

'Create a jar file from your project by running command “gradle clean build” to build the project and then “gradle jar” to generate the jar file. Explain why it is not best recommended to perform this task in this way. '

(HelloWorld.java):

```
package app;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner; 
import com.google.common.collect.Lists; import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List newList = Lists.newArrayList("Hello","World"); 
      String result = Joiner.on(",").join(newList); 
      System.out.println(result);
     } }
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins { 
   id 'java'
   id 'application' }
repositories { 
   jcenter()
} 
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre' 
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2' 
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'

} test {
 useJUnitPlatform() 
}
application {
 mainClassName = 'app.HelloWorld'
}
```

Comment: Could you add the souce of your quote, please.

Comment: @Ludi done(: just added it

Comment: In my opinion, just running "gradle clean build", is 100% fine and should also build the .jar file in build/libs/app.jar . Maybe the answer to the question is that its a duplicated step

Comment: The second invocation is redundant, as *jar* is normally included in *build*. But it doesn't hurt! You can even just `gradle jar` and leave out the first call.

Comment: Additionally, you should almost never need to run `clean`. The only exceptions I can think of is if your build is misconfigured (in which case you should go fix it) or if you have just now made changes to the build so it no longer produces some files, or moves them around, and would like to "clean" up any files from the old setup. If you always run `clean`, you don't get the benefit of [incremental builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks).